# Can't get the value of "relatedto" when sending email through customer portal

Tags: visualforce, email-template, customer-portal

I have visualforce email templates for reset password & welcome email for community users. But relatedto fields are not displaying in the email template. Is it a salesforce issue?

```
<messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="User" relatedToType="Contact" language="{!recipient.LanguageLocaleKey}"
    subject="{!$Label.ResetMailSubject}"
    replyTo="{!recipient.Email}" >

    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >

        <p>{!$Label.WelcomeMailAddressing}  {!relatedTo.Name}</p>
        <p>{!$Label.ResetMailBody}</p>
        <p>{!$Label.ResetMailBodyResetFirst} {!$Network.Name}. {!$Label.ResetMailBodyResetLast}</p>
        <p>{!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails}</p>
        <p>{!$Label.ResetMailBodyWarning}</p>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <p>{!$Label.WelcomeMailClosing}</p>


    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

This is where I am setting the email template in community.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you also share the code that uses the email template?

Comment: There is no code. I have set this email templates in community pages for welcome email & reset password. I have added a image in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting nothing for relatedToType="Contact" is because Contacts, Leads, and Users can't be used in relatedTo (equivalent to the WhatId)

See [Apex Developer Guide outbound Apex email method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_classes_outbound_single) `setWhatId`

> The value must be one of the following types:
>
> Account Asset Campaign Case Contract Opportunity Order Product
>   Solution Custom

Fortunately, `recipientType="User"` provides enough information for you:

```
{!recipient.FirstName}
{!recipient.LastName}
and most other fields on the User record
```

Comment: This solution is not working for community users :(

Comment: @Thirumagal.s So. recipient.email works but not recipient.firstname?

Comment: when I try to display {!recipient.Email} in email body. It is also not coming. I clicked "Reset Password" from community user page LoggedIn as different user. Is that the issue?

Comment: I have added the screenshot in my question for "Reset Password"

Comment: How about recipient.id ?

Comment: same issue for Id also

Comment: @Thirumagal.s take a look at this https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=merge_fields_communities.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null.  Completely different merge fields

Comment: @ cropredy this is working for welcome email. But not working for reset password

Comment: So Receiving_User.Username doesn't work?  Doc says it should.  Also suggests looking at the fields available using the OOTB templates.  @Thirumagal.s

Comment: Finally its working with html email template :) . In html email template only we can use {!Receiving_User.FirstName}. From html email template we can get all the community related fields as well. Thank you for your help !!!

Comment: In order to use these fields which is methioned in this url  we have to use html email template [https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=merge_fields_communities.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null[

Comment: @Thirumagal.s - glad you figured this out; when I have time, i'll dig into the VF issues

Answer (score 0):

Try using `firstname` or `lastname` instead of `name`. Also you can depend on recipient data as well instead of `relatedTo`.

Comment: This solution is not working for community users !!

Comment: Finally its working with html email template :) . In html email template only we can use {!Receiving_User.FirstName}. From html email template we can get all the community related fields as well. Thank you!